# Ruby on Rails How to Integrate GPS Tracking System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gps

I am using following versions

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux],
Rails 4.2.4
```

I have GPS Tracking Devices which works with SMS Commands.when we send sms they reply location,etc. The problem i'm sending SMS through SMS API. now, how can i can get reply and to which server (my server or  server of SMS API providing company)  and how to handle it.
They have given some documentation regarding protocol (works with ASCII codes) that totally i could not understand. 
I am using **Benway Technologies** GPS Tracking Devices.
Kindly, help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a bit this https://benway.en.ec21.com/GPS_Tracker--9810443.html

"...Real-time reporting car status Mainboard support Voice monitor function Check location information via SMS and GPRS(TCP)..."

and this

"...GPS-blue, Power-red Data Transmit TCP..."

Your devices are using GPRS protocol, wich means that they have some IP address. With this functionality, the GPS devices work like a little server, so IT IS POSSIBLE to do what you are looking for: request GPS data to the devices and handle it in your own server.

To achieve this:

1) You need to configure the GPS devices by reprogramming them (via SMS or SERIAL) to allow incoming requests from your server. Also you need to configure your devices to send data to your server.

Just tell to your GPS devices that myownserver.tt or 276.333.456.23(your server public ip) will be the domain / ip to send and receive data via GPRS with TCP protocol.

I have some experience using ENFORA and RUPTELA trackers, there is a a lot of info about them, now, in your case, you must read all the info about your GPS devices, if there is none, just use another brand.

2) You need a proper server to handle incoming TCP data (the GPS devices data). Lets say some Debian based server. To handle the data, you need some script (PHP, Ruby, Java, your choice) in the server to decode this data (NMEA in most cases, you can read more here http: //aprs.gids.nl/nmea/) and then a front end if you wanna see this data (You already have RoR).

3) Rails is a web framework with all the Ruby magic ready for us. You need to do the step 1 and 2 first to integrate a GPS tracking system.

Hope it helps!